# How to print values from nested query in the main select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 3 tables. One is table of trips and connected to table of licence number and that table is connected to table employee. my inner select which is:

```
SELECT  TR.L#, TR.REG# , COUNT(TR.REG#)
FROM TRIP TR
GROUP BY TR.L#, TR.REG#
```

is giving me licence number and truck reg number and number of trip of each licence with that truck. Now I need to add information of licence number which is in another table. How can I transfer these three columns to the main select and print them next to the name of employee?

```
   SELECT  E.FNAME, E.LNAME
    FROM EMPLOYEE E
    WHERE E.E# IN (
            SELECT E#
            FROM DRIVER
            WHERE L# IN (
                        SELECT  TR.L#, TR.REG# , COUNT(TR.REG#)
                         FROM TRIP TR
                    GROUP BY TR.L#, TR.REG#
            )
    );
```

Error:

too many values

Trying JOIN:

```
SELECT   TR.L#, TR.REG# , COUNT(TR.REG#), D.E#  
FROM TRIP TR
INNER JOIN DRIVER D ON D.L# = TR.L#
GROUP BY TR.L#, TR.REG#
```

Comment: yes but I got error: Not a group by expression

Comment: YES i SEE. What is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it's easiest to write the query so that the order of the joins matches the relationships, as if the data flows from trip through driver to employee, along these lines:

```
select tr.l#, tr.reg#, d.e#, count(1) trips
from trip tr
join driver d on (d.l# = tr.l#)
join employee e on (e.e# = d.e#)
group by tr.l#, tr.reg#, d.e#
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  E.FNAME, E.LNAME, sub.<DRIVER FIELD NAME>
FROM EMPLOYEE E JOIN (
            SELECT *
            FROM DRIVER
            WHERE L# IN (
                        SELECT  TR.L#, TR.REG# , COUNT(TR.REG#)
                         FROM TRIP TR
                    GROUP BY TR.L#, TR.REG#
            ) 
    ) sub ON E.E#=sub.E#
```

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification